# Results order with union query

Tags: sql

I have a union query that's getting the count from two different populations. How can I force the results to be returned in the order they're written in the query and not in ascending/descending order?

```
select count(datediff(yyyy,dob,admitdate) as counts
from myTable
where condition
union
select count(datediff(yyyy,dob,admitdate) as counts
from myTable
where condition
```

I'd like for the first result to always be returned as the first row.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to specify the order with an ORDER BY clause.  In your example, you might do:

```
SELECT 1 AS seq, COUNT(datediff(yyyy,dob,admitdate) as counts
  FROM myTable
 WHERE ...condition-1...
UNION
SELECT 2 AS seq, COUNT(datediff(yyyy,dob,admitdate) as counts
  FROM myTable
 WHERE ...condition-2...
 ORDER BY seq
```

Comment: You beat the other guy by eight seconds :).  I'll accept as soon as it lets me.  One more thing: I noticed that you can't name a row like select [row name].  is there any method of naming rows?

Comment: In general, a query returns multiple rows; your COUNT query is unusual in returning just one row in each part of the UNION.  (Incidentally, your query is the same in each part - well, unless we assume two different conditions.)  There isn't a way to 'name' rows (certainly not easily), but the trick of adding a constant like that is reasonably well known.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 1, count(datediff(yyyy,dob,admitdate) as counts
from myTable
where condition
union
select 2, count(datediff(yyyy,dob,admitdate) as counts
from myTable
where condition
order by 1
```