# Order result sets in a UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Results order with union query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555603/results-order-with-union-query)

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

I have 2 selects joined using `UNION`. The second select adds one row. I want this row always show on the bottom. How can I do this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I have the query ordered by the first column which is a char, and it is ordered alphabetically

Comment: @MikeChristensen Why should it do this automatically? There's no mention in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026(v=sql.100).aspx) of preserving the order of data. And since a `UNION` without `ALL` removes duplicates that means there is a high probability that SQL Server will first sort the data internally for processing. As a trivial and artificial example, this returns 1 before 2 for me: `select 2 union select 1 union select 1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can include another column in each part of the union query and use that to sort on:-

```
select col1, col2, col3 from
(
select col1, col2, col3, 1 as sortorder from table1
union
select col1, col2, col3, 2 as sortorder from table2
) as d
order by sortorder, col1
```

This will put the rows from the second select statement after the first one, within which they will be in order of col1.

Note that as you are sorting outside of the inner query the only reason for using union rather than union all is if you want to eliminate duplicates. The duplicates in this case must come from within either of the queries rather than being common to both, because the sortorder column makes them distinct between the two queries. So you probably will want to use union all.

Comment: The thing is im loading this query on SSIS and then exporting to excel as a report......... So, im thinking the new column values would represent nothing to the report.

Comment: @pyram Indeed, the sortorder column values won't appear in the output, but the output will be sorted into order by col1 values from table1 followed by col1 values from table2.